# difference between window.scrollbar and a particular frame.scrollbar

Tags: html, iframe, window

I have a div with a scrollbar in the main window who has also a scrollbar. So, if I use window.scrollbar then it will return the scrolling position of the main scrollbar or my div window's scrollbar? What I need to write if I want to know the position of both the scrollbars? Please explain so it will help me in understanding the stuffs such as frames and window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.scrollbar` doesn't exist AFAIK, it may be some IE specific thing, but it's certainly not standard.  `window.scrollbars` simply gives you information about whether or not the scrollbar is visible on the page.

You want, I believe, `document.body.scrollTop` which tells you how far the page is scrolled, or `div.scrollTop` on your div.